# Чтение файла аннотации к записи ЭКГ-сигнала при использовании функции модуля wfdb

Tags: python-3.x

Здравствуйте, программисты! Пытаюсь прочитать файл аннотации в python, в котором содержится информация  о времени (в отсчётах) возникновения V- или N- комплексов на электрокардиограмме. Синтаксис вызова функции модуля wfdb взял  c github:

import wfdb
ann1 = wfdb.Annotation(recordname='ann1', annotator='atr', sample=[10,20,400],
                       symbol = ['N','N','['], aux_note=[None, None, 'Serious Vfib'])

Вот описание некоторых параметров в функции:

recordname: The base file name (without extension) of the record that the annotation is attached to.

extension: The file extension of the file the annotation is stored in.

sample: The annotation locations in samples relative to the beginning of the record.

symbol: The annotation type according the the standard WFDB codes.

subtype: The marked class/category of each annotation.

chan: The signal channel associated with each annotations.

Вот мой код:
ann1 = wfdb.Annotation('C:/Users/1/Desktop/9 sem/1 zadanie/14134', extension='atr', sample=[10,20,400], symbol = ['V'])

print(ann1[1::, 1])

т.е. если я хочу считать отсчёты со второго столбца, появляется ошибка:
TypeError: 'Annotation' object is not subscriptable

Если же я ввожу пытаюь просто какой-нибудь отдельный элемент вывести, то появляется

TypeError: 'Annotation' object does not support indexing

В чём может быть причина? Спасибо!

p.s. Здесь образец файла аннотации.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: 'Annotation' object is not subscriptable`

Данная ошибка вызывается в случае если объект не массив данных, то есть вероятнее всего переменная на которую ссылается ошибка содержит не перечисляемый тип данных (int, char и т. д.)

`TypeError: 'Annotation' object does not support indexing`

Означает что объект к которому вы пытаетесь получить доступ не имеет метода `__getitem__`, а соответственно не может вернуть что либо по индексу.

Вероятнее всего проблема в попытке обращение к ann1.

Comment: Спасибо, за пояснение, дело в том, что если, например просто выводить файл аннотации, например, print (ann1), тогда появляется странное сообщение: <wfdb.readwrite.annotations.Annotation object at 0x000001F5B0247940>

Comment: @rabbit, Ну я бы не сказал что это странно, вы получаете именно то что просите. Объект и его положение в памяти. Рискну предположить что вы просто не верно пытаетесь получить аннотацию. Прочтите внимательно документацию к библиотеке. Ищите что то вроде Reading или может reading annotation.